# javascript form access

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

```
<form name = "myForm" onsubmit="foo()">
    <p class = "form-text">Name</p>
    <input type = "text" name="name" />
    <input type = "submit" />
</form>

//javascript (external file)
function foo(){
    alert(document.forms["myForm"].name.value)
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this code? When I press submit, it goes to a white page and nothing happens.

The desired result: alert box with value of the name field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never specified what your desired results are, so I can only assume that you would like to see the value alerted with the form submission prevented.

If you *must* use inline javascript, you'll need to use `return false;` to prevent the form submission, although I'm sure you'd like that dependent on the result of `foo()`, so instead of `return false` you can use `return foo();` which will allow you to choose whether or not to prevent the event from happening:

```
onsubmit="return foo()"
///JS
function foo() {
  alert(...);
  return false;
}
```

The problem with code like this is that it directly relies on the HTML calling the JS, which breaks the wonderful MVC structure of HTML CSS and JavaScript. Instead, add the event callback in the JS code:

```
//make sure you add an `[id]` to your form
var form = document.getElementsById('formid');
form.onsubmit = foo;

function foo() {
  //do stuff
  return false;
}
```

Comment: In your second example, all that code must be inserted in a document.ready body or something like that, right?

Comment: @TGM, only if the script is executed before that particular section of the dom is loaded. If you add your script references at the end of the body, there's no reason to wait for `document.onreadystatechange`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<form name = "myForm" onsubmit="foo();return false;">
    <p class = "form-text">Name</p>
    <input type = "text" name="name" />
    <input type = "submit" />
</form>

//javascript
function foo(){
    alert(document.forms["myForm"].name.value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't prevent the submission of the form. Rewrite your function to return either `true` or `false` depending on your intention (`true` for "send it" and `false` for "don't send it"). Then use `onsubmit="return foo();"`, which will then directly influence the submission of the form depending on the return value of `foo()`.